# Adding a button to an excel worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have 3 worksheets in my current workbook. Worksheet 1 and 2 both have macros in it. Worksheet 1 macro extracts the necessary columns and copies results directly into worksheet 3. Worksheet 2 macro extracts the columns and the after certain additional calculation (done in separate columns) references the results (worksheet 2) in worksheet 3. This way worksheet 3 has the final output.

Is there a way that I can just add one button on worksheet 3 that would run macro 1 on worksheet 1 and run macro 2 on worksheet 2 so that I can get the final desired output in worksheet 3?

Comment: Just assign a macro to the button which calls both of the other macros.

Comment: @jsheeran. I tried doing that, but it does not execute the macro in worksheet 2. I have the following code: `Call CopyCodeA
    Call CopyCodeB` inside a function RunAll

Comment: Create a macro and in that put `Call CopyCodeA` next line `Call CopyCodeB`, and assign the name of this new macro to a button/shape etc.

Comment: Just adding to the comment by @TimWilkinson: make sure that the macros on both sheets are **not** private (but public).

Comment: @Ralph do we have to declare a function as Public or does Excel consider a function to be Public by default unless specified?

Comment: @TimWilkinson. I added the following macro, but it still keeps giving me an error "Sub or function not defined". `Sub Run_All()` next line
    `Call CopyCodeA` next line `Call CopyCodeB` next line `End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sure hope the following screen-cast can shed some light on your multitude of questions (what works, what doesn't, how to call a sheet macro from a module, what's the default if private / public is not explicitly defined, etc.):

[image]

Let me know if you have any more questions or if you are still failing to call the sheet-macros from the module.

Comment: Yes! That indeed helped a lot. Thank You.